# How many permutations of the word $STRESSLESSNESS$ begin OR end with an $E$?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many permutations of the word $STRESSLESSNESS$ begin OR end with an $E$?

Correct me if I'm wrong, but you would have to subtract the permutations where $E$ begins AND ends the permutation?

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you figure the number of permutations that start with E?  The number that end with E?  Yes, if you add those together you have then double counted the ones that start and end with E.

Comment: I believe in the english language the "or" is assumed to be inclusive unless otherwise stated. Maybe in other languages the exclusive or would be the default. So to subtract or not the permutations where E begins AND ends with E depends on how you ask. As stated here you should not.

Comment: You could also find the total arrangements and subtract the number of them that neither start or end with an E

Comment: @RianKoja  that is true, but Ross's comment is correct:  when adding permutations Beginning in E, to those ending in E, we will have counted twice the permutations that both begin with E and end with E.  So your comment is irrelevant here.

Answer (score 3):

- $E\underbrace{------------}_{12 \text {letter}}E$
  Result: $\frac{12}{7!}$ , since there are seven $S$'s among the remaining letters(STRSSLSSNESS) we divide by $7!$ to eliminate overcounting
- $E\underbrace{-------------}_{13 \text {letter}}$
  Result: $\frac{13}{2!7!}$ ,since there are seven $S$'s and two $E$'s among the remaining letters(STRSSLESSNESS) we divide by $7!2!$  to eliminate overcounting
- $\underbrace{-------------}_{13 \text {letter}}E$
  Result: $\frac{13}{2!7!}$ , again since there are seven $S$'s and two $E$'s among the remaining letters(STRSSLESSNESS) we divide by $7!2!$  to eliminate overcounting

But remember $2nd$ and $3rd$ cases contain $1st$ case as well. So, we need to handle that overcounting too by substracting $1st$ result from $2nd$ and $3rd$ results.

So, in total: $\frac{12}{7!}+(\frac{13}{2!7!}-\frac{12}{7!})+ (\frac{13}{2!7!}-\frac{12}{7!})$

Comment: Or, simply, $2\cdot \frac{13}{2!7!} - \frac{12}{7!}$

Comment: Sure ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2):

*STRESSLESSNESS* is 14 letters long.

If we take away an **e**, it becomes 13 letters long.

The permutations of this 13 letter string is:

$$\frac{13!}{7!2!}$$

Since the **E** can occur at the beginning or the end, we multiply this by 2 to get:
$$\frac{13!}{7!}$$

We then take into account a possibility of an E at the beginning and at the end:

$$\frac{13!}{7!}-\frac{12!}{7!}=1140480$$

Comment: Your answer is incorrect since you have counted sequences that both begin and end with an E twice.

Comment: Yes I realised that just as I posted it. It's been edited now

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing it is this:

number that begins with an E, plus number than ends with an E, minus number that both begins and ends with an E.

Another way is this:

First find the total number of permutations, then subtract the number that begin and end with a non-E.